# Parse objects overriding when using Local Datastore

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm facing a weird issue using Parse's Local Datastore.

I have a Cloud function declared in backend that returns a list of ParseUsers, which can returns my current User.

The problem is when the function returns my User in the list, local currentUser gets overrided by the server data, resulting in a lost of information (i.e. authData).

Reading documentation from Parse I found this:

> There are a couple of side effects of enabling the local datastore
>   that you should be aware of. When enabled, there will only be one
>   instance of any given ParseObject. For example, imagine you have an
>   instance of the "GameScore" class with an objectId of "xWMyZ4YEGZ",
>   and then you issue a ParseQuery for all instances of "GameScore" with
>   that objectId. The result will be the same instance of the object you
>   already have in memory.

I think this may be causing the problem.

Have you got any idea how to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found that this is due to a know Bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/898928300168631/?search_id